# How do I get my acronyms out of the main glossary?

Tags: glossaries

I am writing my thesis and I must have a list of the abbreviations used.  I'm using the acronym part of the glossaries package in LaTeX, and all went fine, until the number of acronyms broke, I think, 30, and then the extra ones went away.  I tried deleting all of the files except the .tex file, and that got rid of the entire list of abbreviations.  Upon further inspection, I found that all of my acronyms were being deposited in the main glossary instead of the acronyms list.  So, my question is: How do I get my acronyms back into the acronyms glossary.  Here's an example of what I am doing

```
%\usepackage{variousPackages}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossary[alg]{acronym}{acr}{acn}{Glossary of Abbreviations Used}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\newacronym{th}{th}{this}
\newacronym{ta}{ta}{that}
\printglossary[type=acronym]
%rest of the document
\gls{th}
\gls{ta}
%the rest of the rest of the document
\end{document}
```

If I tell LaTex to just print all of the glossaries, it will print the main glossary with the list of abbreviations.  If I use the above code, it prints no abbreviations.  The `\gls` commands still work.  The list of acronyms simply doesn't show up unless I allow LaTeX to print the main glossary.

I have tried recompiling the code many times and using a makeglossaries perl script mentioned in another question on something similar, but so far, nothing has worked.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am working with the latest verison of MikTex, and WinEdt 9.0, for Windows.
This seems like it might be something obvious, so I apologize if this has an obvious answer, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Again, thank you for any help you can give

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think you're screwing up `glossaries` completely. There is already an `acronym` feature and **no** need to use a `\newglossary` for this. And reading the manual would help here in as much that it would recommend you to provide the glossary/acronym definitions before `\begin{document}`. Use the `acronym` option to the package loading as well!

Comment: If my recommendations provide no help, please add a compilable version of your document

Comment: I tried adding them before the `\begin{document}` and it gave me errors.  That is why they are in the document.  As for declaring `\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries}`, how would I go about renaming the glossary to "Glossary of Abbreviations Used" then?

Comment: Since you haven't used the `acronym` package option, `\acronymtype` is set to `main`. This means that `\newacronym` is putting the entries into the `main` glossary.

Comment: Sorry, our comments crossed :-). `\printglossary[title={Glossary of Abbreviations},type=acronym]`

Comment: It worked!  It would seem that the problem was a combination of me having the `\newacronym` declarations after the `\begin{document}` and misusing the acronym part of the package.  Thank you so much :-)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Will you provide an answer or shall we close this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I'll add an answer. It may be useful to others.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot: Well, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

`\newacronym` sets `type=\acronymtype` unless overridden in the optional argument. The default value of `\acronymtype` is `\glsdefaulttype` (usually the `main` glossary) unless the `acronym` package option is used, in which case `\acronymtype` is set to `acronym`. Since you're manually defining the acronym glossary using `\newglossary`, the acronyms are put in the `main` glossary. So you have the following options:

1. Manually set the `type` in the optional argument of `\newacronym`.
2. Redefine `\acronymtype` to the label of your custom glossary.
3. Use the `acronym` package option and set the title with the `title` key in `\printglossary` (or [change the fixed name](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:fixednames)).

The other side-issue is that, [as recommended in the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec:docdefs), definitions are best made in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`).